# mq_open invalid Arugument & how to debug linux kernel in this case

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, posix

In process A, I open the queue like this:

```
struct mq_attr attr;
attr.mq_flags = 0;
attr.mq_maxmsg = 10;
attr.mq_msgsize = sizeof(GetMoreReq);
mq_open(name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_NONBLOCK, 0664, &attr)
```

In Process B: I want to open the same queue, with

```
mq_open(mq_name, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK)
```

However I get error: " Invalid argument“

I can't figure out what is wrong.  so my question are:

1. what is the problem here?
2. is it possible to step into the mq_open function after I install some package?  if so, I can see where the error is raised.

My OS version Ubuntu 18.04:

```
Linux ubuntu-zhifan 4.15.0-43-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 6 14:45:28 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Have you already checked with `strace` that the arguments match what you expect?

Comment: The name is not correctly, thanks for the hint